# CodeName One - Image gets pixelated when scaling

Tags: image, codenameone

I am getting an image dynamically from a webservice. Afterwards I am supposed to use it as background for the upper half of the screen. My problem is that I only get one size of the image (which should be approximately right for many smartphones phones) but when I resize it to make it fill half of the screen it gets pixelated.
I have tried putting it as background of a container (adding padding to the expected size) and using BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL and/or using Image methods scaledHeight/scaledWidth, fill and scaled.
It doesn't matter if I scale it to a bigger or smaller size it still deteriorates noticeably.

Is this to be expected? Is there another way to scale images?

```
public class CopyOfVistaPantallaPrincipal extends VistaDisparaEventos {

    private Container canvasPantallaPrincipal;

    public CopyOfVistaPantallaPrincipal() {
        canvasPantallaPrincipal = new Container();
        canvasPantallaPrincipal.setName("canvasPantallaPrincipal");
        super.canvas = this.canvasPantallaPrincipal;
        initPantallaPrincipal();
    }

    private void initPantallaPrincipal() {

        canvasPantallaPrincipal.setLayout(new LayeredLayout());
        canvasPantallaPrincipal.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

        ModeloNovedades modelo = new ModeloNovedades();

        Image imgPrincipal = createImagenPrincipal(modelo);
        canvasPantallaPrincipal.setName("canvas pantalla principal");

        Container otro = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        if (imgPrincipal != null) {
            img.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(null);
            img.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            img.getUnselectedStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
            canvasPantallaPrincipal.addComponent(img);
        }
        canvasPantallaPrincipal.addComponent(otro);
    }

    private Container createImagenPrincipal(ModeloNovedades modelo) {
        return loadTopImage(modelo, modelo.getDestacado());
    }

    private Container loadTopImage(ModeloNovedades modelo, Hashtable destacado) {       
        int width = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
        int imgHeight = (int) ((Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() / 2) * 0.95) ;

        //Default image
        Image foregroundImage = FormFactory.loadImage("/imagenPrincipaLogoOld.png");

        if (! modelo.getDestacado().isEmpty()){
            String destacadaURL = "" + destacado.get("imagen");
            if (! destacadaURL.equals("")){
                //After updating it loads the downloaded image here
                byte[] data = (byte[]) DataCenter.getInstance().get(destacadaURL, false);
                foregroundImage = FormFactory.loadImage(data, 100);
            }
         }

        imageContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(imgHeight/2, imgHeight/2, width/2, width()/2);
        imageContainer.getAllStyles().setBgImage(foregroundImage);
        imageContainer.getAllStyles().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);

        return imageContainer;
    }
```

}

If I'm not returning the image but a container having it as background I would add it to a Container like this:

```
imageContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(imgHeight/2, imgHeight/2, width/2, width/2);
imageContainer.getAllStyles().setBgImage(foregroundImage);
imageContainer.getAllStyles().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED); //only if it was scaled
```

Original image (please ignore the dark bar over it, it was added recently and I didn't save the previous version, as I said it comes dynamically):
http://i68.tinypic.com/16lmeqr.jpg

Scaled:
http://i68.tinypic.com/w7zafm.jpg

Cropped:
http://i65.tinypic.com/2nkp79l.png

Image as of the last update:
http://i68.tinypic.com/2ik7eiq.png

Comment: Scaling will deteriorate image quality. That is a given. If you will provide code, the actual image file & screenshots I'll be able to help more.

Comment: Added the requested info. (I'm sorry if this causes a double notification to pop up, I'm not sure how SO works)

Answer (score 1):

Remove all of your code that manipulates the image, needs scaling, scale etc... That is all redundant. Every pass you do on manipulating an image deteriorates it a little bit...

You need just one line change and you need to do it always so the image will always "fit" without cropping or any other changes:
    imageContainer.getAllStyles().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALE_TO_FILL);

Notice that you can just use `ScaleImageLabel` instead of image container which does roughly the same thing.

Comment: I suppose you mean BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL as the other constant doesn't seem to be defined. Updated my code in the question, is this what you meant? As shown in the last screenshot it still gets slightly wrong.

Comment: It's unclear from the code what loadImage does and how you download the image which might include some scaling logic. Also make sure your simulator has scrolling enabled to show a better representation of how the image will look on the device, without that the simulator scales and will include artifacts. Notice that if you use the screenshot feature of the simulator the scrolling flag doesn't matter